# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS only boots with Recovery Mode with Linux 4.7.2 After Upgrade

Tags: grub2, 17.10, 17.04, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

0
down vote
favorite

Upon performing an upgrade from Ubuntu 17 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, my PC was in standby mode, thereby interrupting the last 1/4 portion of the upgrade. When trying to boot normally- "Ubuntu*"; "Linux 4.7.2", the machine loads the drive and asks for password. Then the screen just goes blank. If I boot into 4.7.2 recovery mode, I am able to access Ubuntu 18.04 and login.

Grub configuration is at i8042.reset nomodeset. Previously it was set to quiet splash. Neither has solved the boot issue.

What can I do to solve the interrupted upgrade process (to where the upgrade did not successfully complete during running in Ubuntu 17), and to where I can boot into Ubuntu without recovery mode?

LSB Version: core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Release: 18.04 Codename: bionic

4.7.2-040702-generic #201608201334 SMP Sat Aug 20 17:37:03 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Don't think you can do much, also, where does "Linux 4.7.2" come from?

Comment: That is the linux kernel I am running.

Comment: Problem solved by Installing MBR in grub-customizer still need to add a quicker bootload process.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @user1780064: I'd encourage you to post the details of [your solution as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). You can then mark that answer as the accepted one (though the system will require that you wait two days to do so).